# whats the proper way to make dependent api call in react redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

In my application, we maintain an inventory of authors and books and the vendors who are selling those books.

In my react js app I have a home page which displays  a table with a list of authors and when we click on any author we go to author details page and URL will be like ${url}/author/12 . This author details page consists of three sections .First div contains author details like name, city, country.Second div contains list of books author has published so far which is a table and by default first record is selected.Third div contains the details of each book like title, description, price when a book is selected from second div .

In this author details page i use the id from props.match.params.id and make first api call to fetch author details, if success then fetch books if that is success get selected book details. I am confused between two approaches i have.

Method 1:

Make all the api calls from ui component based on data recieved. Make use of componentwillReceiveProps to know when the author details are fetched or books are fetched. Is componentwillReceiveProps the right place to decide to make subsequent api calls ?

```
        class AuthorPage extends React.Component {

      state = {
        authorId:this.props.match.params.id,
      }

      componentDidMount() {
        this.props(fetchAuthorDetails(authorId));
      }


      componentWillReceiveProps(newProps){
        //Is this the right place to decide the subsequent api calls ?
        if(isNotEmpty(newProps.author.details))
          {
            this.props(fetchAuthorBooks(authorId));
          }
          else if (newProps.author.books.length > 0 && isNotEmpty(newProps.author.selectedBook)){
            this.props(fetchSelectedBookDetails(newProps.author.selectedBook.id));
          }
      }


      render() {
        // UI render code goess here
      }


    }

    const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => bindActionCreators(
      {
        fetchAuthorDetails,
        fetchAuthorBooks,
        fetchSelectedBookDetails
      },
      dispatch,
    )

    const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => ({
        authorDetails: state.author.details,
        books: state.author.books,
        selectedBook: state.author.selectedBook,
        selectedBookDetails : state.author.selectedBook.details
      });

      export default connect(mapStateToProps)(AuthorPage);
```

Method2:

Is it better to make Subsequent dispatch calls  (from ActionCreators dispatch calls depending on success/fail) like I am calling authorDetailsSuccess /BooksActionCreators.getAuthorBookDetails and authorDetailsError/ErrorsActionsCreator in the below code? And  should i have separate action creators file for authors and books.

```
    export function fetchAuthorDetails(authorId) {
      dispatch(authorDetailsStart());
      return dispatch =>
        fetch('http://localhost/api', {
          method: 'get',
          headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            email: userData.email,
            password: userData.password,
          }),
        })
        .then(response => {
          if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
            console.log(response);
            dispatch(authorDetailsSuccess(authorDetails));
            dispatch(BooksActionCrerators.getAuthorBookDetails(authorDetails.id)); //is this the right place to chain
          } else {
            const error = new Error(response.statusText);
            error.response = response;
            dispatch(authorDetailsError());
            dispatch(ErrorsActionsCreator.sendError(error));
            throw error;
          }
        })
        .catch(error => { console.log('request failed', error); });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I always add `redux-thunk` module to my projects. This module transform a simple redux action to a promise-like function. So I can concatenate multiple actions by using classic `.then()` sintax. Check [documentation](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) for more details.

Comment: While i know that approach i would like to know which approach is better method 1 ui or method 2 in the redux action creators api call

Comment: Second solution is better. In first case, you also have to check if your prop now is not empty but before it was, and so call the second api, but also you have to check if it is changed to call second api again to update data, and so on... More complicated.